# Geeting Redis memory peak issue

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, redis

I've deployed the project on AWS & we are using local Redis. We have around 150+ Redis keys. having a lot of data. We have 16 GB RAM on the EC2 instance & in Redis config, we defined **maxmemory 10 GB**.

But we are getting bellow error.

--> redis-cli

--> memory doctor

Sam, I detected a few issues in this Redis instance memory implants:

- Peak memory: In the past this instance used more than 150% the memory that is currently using. The allocator is normally not able to release memory after a peak, so you can expect to see a big fragmentation ratio, however this is actually harmless and is only due to the memory peak, and if the Redis instance Resident Set Size (RSS) is currently bigger than expected, the memory will be used as soon as you fill the Redis instance with more data. If the memory peak was only occasional and you want to try to reclaim memory, please try the MEMORY PURGE command, otherwise the only other option is to shutdown and restart the instance.

I'm here to keep you safe, Sam. I want to help you.

That would be great if anyone can help us to resolve this as soon as possible.

Please let us know.